# Merge named vectors in different sizes into data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, merge, sum

I have some different named vectors, and I want to combine them into one date frame that sums the actions.

```
 adjust balance   drive    idle   other    pick putdown replace    sort    wait 
      4       9      16      82       4     350      61      16      26      18 
   walk 
     14 

 adjust balance   drive    idle    pick putdown replace    sort  unload    walk 
      1      42      14      47     385     118       4      83      19       7
```

i want it to be this way:

```
 adjust balance   drive  
      5       51      30
```

and etc..

i find it very challenging because those are named vectors
would be grateful for your help, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `aggregate` + `stack` like below

```
aggregate(. ~ ind, rbind(stack(vec1), stack(vec2)), sum)
```

Comment: Fantastic answer Thomas. Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to a `data.frame` and use the `dplyr` package to group by the names and sum the numbers together.

```
library(dplyr)
vec <- c(4, 9, 16, 1, 42, 14)
names(vec) <- c("adjust", "balance", "drive", "adjust", "balance", "drive")
data.frame(values = vec, name = names(vec)) %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(values = sum(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to add all elements that match between the two vectors:

```
# Resolve the matching names of the vectors:
# vec_nm_order => character vector
vec_nm_order <- intersect(
   names(vec1),
   names(vec2)
)

# Add the related scalars together:
# named integer vector => stdout(console)
vec1[vec_nm_order] + vec2[vec_nm_order]
```

If we only want to add values for adjust, balance, drive:

```
# Choose the names (keys) of elements we want to add together:
# vec_nm_order => character vector
vec_nm_order <- c(
   "adjust", "balance", "drive"
)

# Add the related scalars together:
# named integer vector => stdout(console)
vec1[vec_nm_order] + vec2[vec_nm_order]
```